# Why I not getting any output from JSON after parsing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data[0].name);
}
```

Output on console:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Apple"}]
undefined
```

Where is problem in the code? I want to use this output in  tag

```
<option value="' + data[0].id + '"'>' + data[0].name + </option>
```

Comment: "_... after parsing ..._" but you're not parsing `data` ... Notice also, that JS variables are not parsed into HTML markup like it seems you're expecting them to be parsed.

Comment: You can refer on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object

Answer (score 4):

Your data variable seems to be string. You will need to parse it first.

Try following

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data[0].name);
```

For reference, [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Have you tried the same way as the answer? Did the log correctly showed the data or is it somewhere else in the code?

Comment: Yes the same way as in the answer I am getting data from server as: [{"id":1,"name":"Apple"}]  its in the form of an array